# Proving $\vdash_{HPI}A\vee(B\vee C) \rightarrow (A\vee B)\vee C $

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, hilbert-calculus

Prove $\vdash_{HPI}A\vee(B\vee C) \rightarrow (A\vee B)\vee C $

From the axioms :

A1) A→(B→A)

A2) (A→(B→C))→((A→B)→(A→C))

A3) $(A\rightarrow B)\rightarrow((A\rightarrow\neg B)\rightarrow \neg A)$

A4) $\neg A\rightarrow A\rightarrow B$

A5) (A∧B)→A

A6) (A∧B)→B

A7) A→(B→(A∧B))

A8) A→(A∨B)

A9) B→(A∨B)

A10) (A→B)→((C→B)→((A∨C)→B))

and MP

I know by the deduction theorem it is enough to show $A\vee(B\vee C) \vdash_{HPI} (A\vee B)\vee C $.

It's clearly true because of associativity. However, I'm not sure how to prove it formally using only the axioms above.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the [Hilbert-style proof system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Hilbert_systems) for propositional calculus above, we can use the "derived rule" of [Hypothetical Syllogism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypothetical_syllogism) :

> $A \to B, B \to C \vdash A \to C$.

With it, we have:

1) $B \to (A \lor B)$

2) $(A \lor B) \to (A \lor B) \lor C$

3) $B \to (A \lor B) \lor C$ --- from 1) and 2) by *HS*

4) $C \to (A \lor B) \lor C$

> 5) $B \lor C \to (A \lor B) \lor C$ --- from 3) and 4) by A10) and *Modus Ponens* twice

6) $A \to (A \lor B)$

7) $(A \lor B) \to (A \lor B) \lor C$

> 8) $A \to (A \lor B) \lor C$ --- from 6) and 7) by *HS*
>
> > 9) $A \lor (B \lor C) \to (A \lor B) \lor C$ --- from 5) and 8) by A10) and *Modus Ponens* twice.

---

In order to prove *Hypothetical Syllogism*, we have :

1. $A \rightarrow B$ --- premise
2. $B \rightarrow C$ --- premise
3. $(B \rightarrow C) \rightarrow  (A \rightarrow (B \rightarrow C))$ --- A1)
4. $A \rightarrow (B \rightarrow C)$ --- from 2) and 3) by *MP*
5. $(A \rightarrow (B \rightarrow C)) \rightarrow ((A \rightarrow B) \rightarrow (A \rightarrow C))$ --- A2)
6. $(A \rightarrow B) \rightarrow (A \rightarrow C)$ --- from 4) and 5) by *MP*

> 7. $A \rightarrow C$ --- from 1) and 6) by *MP*.

Comment: Anytime derived rules get used, what gets written is NOT *in* the proof system.  Thus, derived rules can't get used *in* a proof system.  They can only get used metalogically.  Anyways, this sort of point didn't really matter to the user, and maybe you keep sharp with such statements as "In the Hilbert-style proof system for propositional calculus above, we can use the "derived rule" of Hypothetical Syllogism" even if inaccurate.

Comment: @DougSpoonwood - this is your opinion :-) It is like using a subroutine in a computer program: it works perfectly well.

Comment: I'm not sure I agree with your analogy.  When you use a derived rule of inference, it's more like the computer program might write that the function is undefined.  That said, I guess one might analogically claim that using a derived rule of inference is like using part of an imported library.